# Zurb Foundation Framework seems to be causing menus to change state

Tags: javascript, wordpress, drop-down-menu, breakpoints, zurb-foundation-6

The site was created by a third party, using wordpress and the zurb foundation framework. My main nav menu is having it's 'accordion' classes changed to 'dropdown' classes at 40em screen width and I cannot figure out where the instruction is coming from.

I have searched through everything I can think of to figure this out and I have come up empty handed.